# What is the good way of setting JAVA_HOME system wide in Linux? /etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/custom.sh?

Tags: java-home

There doesn't seem to be an official answer as to where to set your system wide JAVA_HOME in Linux, at least I haven't found one (looked on Oracle website and some google fu). 
Many forums and comments point at setting it in /etc/profile or even /etc/bashrc/ (or /etc/bashrc.bashrc) but on my system both these files headers are quite specific about creating

> "a custom.sh shell script in /etc/profile.d/ [...] as this will
>   prevent the need for merging in future updates."

instead of directly modifying the files.

For this reason I'm thinking the custom.sh shell script placed in /etc/profile.d is the way to go but I might be missing something hence this question =)

Please forgive me if I missed an official doc and just post the link!

---

Comment: Depends on your distribution. That's what docs you should be looking at.

Comment: It depends on the distribution (as @Mat already pointed out), but whatever you do: do not edit it into bashrc as this wouldn't affect different shells. /etc/profile should work in most cases. (This question would be more appropriate to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [UNIX and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) though)

Comment: I hesitated with posting on SuperUser because it's JDK/JRE related maybe the admins will flag and move over there?I don't think I can move it myself. As for being distro dependent on rpms based ones the "yum install" from official repository doesn't seem to modify /etc/profile nor does it add a file in /etc/profile.d yet it must set JAVA_HOME somewhere, right? Install docs are pretty slim and haven't found any mention about how to set your JAVA_HOME on any official doc for CentOS nor RHEL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question with the paragraph beginning "For this reason...".  The only time I edit `/etc/profile` is when I'm *changing* some value in it (rather than adding something).

When adding various software packages which require changing user profiles, most distros add an appropriate script to the `/etc/profile.d` directory, and the base-installed `/etc/profile` script has a call to all executable scripts in that directory.  (Likewise, upgrading/removing the distro-provided package will have the script in the subdirectory modified or removed.)

Answer (score 15):

I usually make a java_dev.sh file in /etc/profile.d/ containing:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/javahome
export M2_HOME=/opt/mavenhome
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Or the like. I use this on all Linuxen I frequently use, Ubuntu, RH, Fedora...