# Issues in installation of grails in Linux

Tags: java, linux, grails, environment-variables, java-home

I was following this video for installation of grails on a virtual machine (Centos-OS, Linux) : [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zshNRKytyFk)

It was done once successfully, but while doing this process in another VM, I got stuck in the process after jdk installation. I installed GVM  successfully, after restarting the terminal, I get an error :

```
GVM: JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please set JAVA_HOME.
```

I googled the error and changed the environment variable many times, but nothing has removed the error as the variables get changed only for that instance, and it does not stay after that instance

I also got inside bash_profile, but I am not able to edit the file and save it.

Also, I am not able to find the exact location as I do not have access to the VM window where I can actually navigate and check directories.
I only have access to the main terminal of the VM wherein I have to resolve this error to go ahead and install grails using GVM

How do I resolve this issue?  What am I doing wrong here?
All suggestions/approaches are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a file for setting `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile.d/`. 
I have set up grails with gvm on Centos 5.9 (with vagrant) [like this](https://gist.github.com/jefferysmith/6559128).

Keep in mind that this would be a system-wide setting. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10117943/1024571)

Comment: went through both your links, I am really not able to understand what to do in the first link.
In the second link, I again don;t understand what I need to do in the "/etc/profile" link. 
Can you please elaborate and help me with that?

Comment: You need to create a file (as root) under /etc/profile.d/. For example, `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`. Inside this file export your JAVA_HOME variable. For example `export JAVA_HOME=<java install directory>`

Comment: Also, take a look at [this example](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) to make sure that you have correctly installed the JDK on RH/CentOS

Answer (score 0):

add export JAVA_HOME= {your java home}
at the top of
{userhome}/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh

Answer (score 0):

add export JAVA_HOME= {your java home} at the top of {userhome}/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh (credits DannyM)

In my case I used nano to edit the gvm-init.sh

calyx@DJ:/$ sudo nano /home/calyx/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh

then added 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

on top of 
export GVM_VERSION="2.4.1"
export GVM_PLATFORM=$(uname)